# Permutation models: when are they isomorphic?

Tags: set-theory

Let $M, M'$ be two permutations models with atoms $A,A'$. Assume $A$ and $A'$ have the same cardinality so that there is a bijection $f: A \to A'$. Now assume $M$ and $M'$ are defined in terms of the same filter: if $F$ is the filter of $M$ then $F'$ is the filter obtained from $F$ by applying $f$. It seems clear to me that $M $ and $M'$ model the same theory.

The following is an example: Let $A=A'$ be any countably infinite set. For $M$ let the group of permutations be *all* permutations of $A$. For $M'$ let $G'$ be the group of permutations that only permute a finite number of atoms $a \in A$. Certainly, $G'$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Take both $F$ and $F'$ to be the filter of permutations that fix finitely many $a \in A$.

I think that $M$ and $M'$ in the example model the same theory because the group $G$ has no influence on the resulting permutation model, only the filter does.

My question: Is it true that $M$ and $M'$ as in my example model the same theory or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two models in your example give the same model, but it's not true generally that "the group $G$ has no influence ... only the filter does."

Consider, for example, Mostowski's linearly ordered model.  Here the set $A$ of atoms is equipped with a linear order isomorphic to the rationals (in the full universe satisfying AC, not in the permutation submodel), the group consists of all order-preserving permutations of $A$, and the filter is given by finite supports (as in your examples).  Now consider a second model, using the same $A$, the group of *all* permutations of $A$ (not just order-preserving ones), and the filter given by finite supports.  These models satisfy quite different sentences.  For example, the first satisfies "every set can be linearly ordered" and the second does not.

The reason the groups in your example made no difference is that $G'$ is dense in $G$ with respect to the topology on $G$ that has $F$ as a basis of neighborhoods of the identity.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I apologise in advance because I will take some time before I accept your answer because I need some time to properly understand it.

Comment: Regarding the statement in your last sentence: is the proof of it something a first year grad student can figure out with a bit of thinking or would it be wise if I kindly requested you to point me to a book (or paper) where I can read a proof? Perhaps my problem is not the actual proof but making the connection between the topology and truth of statements in the model so perhaps I should ask for a reference to that?

Comment: I'm not sure the proof of this density result has been written up, so I hope you can figure it out. A big hint is that the permutation models built using $G$ and $G'$ not only are models of the same theory but are in fact exactly the same model.  A set is (hereditarily) symmetric with respect to $G$ iff it is so with respect to  $G'$. I think this is not too difficult to check after you unravel what density means for this topology.

Comment: Andreas, does it have anything to do with [this paper by Brunner](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1043792)?

Comment: Asaf, I'm not familiar with that paper, but, from the review that you linked to, it seems to be doing more complicated things --- in particular changing the type of support, rather than just passing to a dense subgroup.